# Equivalence relation in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Every set of positive measure has non measurable subsets and, moreover:

$\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{L}  \iff \lambda(A)=0$

How would you go about proving this? Cant get my head around it

Note: $\mathcal{L}=\{B \cup N : B \in \mathcal{B}, N \in \mathcal{N} \}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel ($\sigma$)-algebra, $\mathcal{N}$ is the set of null sets

Comment: Can you prove that $\lambda(A)=0$ implies $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: No, I dont think i can

Comment: $\lambda(A)=0\implies A\in\mathcal{N}$.  You want to show that $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{L}$, which is equivlent to showing that $B\subseteq A$ implies $B\subseteq\mathcal{L}$.